# GET command not found

Tags: http

I am a in a student job where I am required to do work with a DB but it really isn't my domain.

In the Documentation it says to enter the line

```
GET /_cat/health?v
```

This returns the error

```
-bash: GET: command not found
```

It also proposes that I copy as curl. Then the command that works is

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
```

I can I make the command "GET /_cat/health?v" to work?

Comment: GET command will not directly work in the terminal. 'GET' is the request type, you need to set it when accessing this API.  Follow this link more information https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 2):

`GET` is a [request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) of the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol. If you don't write an HTTP server or client software then you don't have to deal with it explicitly.

The command line

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
```

tells [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to request the URL `http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty` using the `GET` [request method](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X).

`GET` is the default method, you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Also, the second argument you provide to `curl` is not an URL. `curl` is nice and completes it to a correct URL but other programs that expect URLs might not work the same (for various reasons). It's better to always specify complete URLs to get the behaviour you expect.

Your command line should be:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
```

The apostrophes around the URL are required because it contains characters that are special to the shell (`&`). A string enclosed in apostrophes tells the shell to not interpret any special characters inside it.

Without the apostrophes, the shell thinks the `curl` command ends on `&` and `pretty` is a different command and the result is not what you expect.

Behind the scene, `curl` uses `HTTP` to connect to the server `localhost` on port `9200` and sends it this [HTTP request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message):

```
GET /_cat/health?v&pretty
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start working with elasticsearch, one of the first things they ask you to do to test your install is to do a GET /_cat/health?v, as shown here:
[enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-install.html)

They fail to tell you that this will not work in a terminal, as Ravi Sharma has explained above.  Maybe the elasticsearch team should clarify this a bit.  At least they supply a Copy as cURL link.  It is just frustrating for someone new at this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libwww-perl
```

GET command is in package libwww-perl